# How can experienced people post their knowledge and new research?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, instant-self-answer

As Stack Overflow serves as a platform for users to ask and answer questions, it  provides a huge platform for questions and answers on a wide range of topics in programming.

Is there anyway through which experience people can post their knowledge and new research, so that knowledge-eager people can follow them?

Comment: Research these day cannot be explained in a small post, and are usually focused on some small area. If it happens not to be the case, and the research is widely applicable, and there is a real problem that needs solving, then a question/answer is appropriate. Otherwise, I **don't** think SO is a good place to display or consume new research.

Comment: Also, (add-on question) how would the CC-Wiki license figure in with respect to original research that may later be published ?

Comment: @nhahtdh yeah you are right

Comment: A good way to spread knowledge and research can be through blog posts.

Comment: @AshRj That shouldn't be a restriction. If you are the original author of the work, none of your rights are affected. It might have publishers require that you add a substantial amount of new information to your work, but that should in most cases be easy enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you think some of your research or knowledge is useful for others then you can put that in a question and answer it right away.

There is even an checkbox for that on the bottom of the asking page saying

> Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style

[image: asking]

That is [highly encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)!

And you can mark your answer as *community wiki* if you feel you should not earn for both (question and answer) reputation.

Comment: nice idea, we can share like this

Comment: @YadavChetan Do keep in mind that we are a Q&A however. Spend as much effort on your question (if not more) as you do on your answer. If your question is bad, it will be closed. No matter how interesting or polished your answer is.

Comment: @Bart yeah this may be the case

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Juergen's answer, about answering your own question.

In addition, you can create or revise the tag wiki for existing tags, if you have enough rep.

This can be a useful way to propagate knowledge about some particular subject matter.  You do have to make sure that the scope of your remarks and the scope of the tag overlap, for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, sharing knowledge in the form of questions and answers is perfectly accepted, and even encouraged.

But! Most page views seem to be driven by Google searches, so if you want anyone to find your work you need to make sure that it is expressed in the terms that people use when they search in Google. Since people don't tend to use the same vocabulary as the average CS research paper to describe real life development challenges, you might want to work on that aspect, too.